# Is it possible to enable server-based SharePoint integration programmatically?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-dynamics, sharepoint-online, dynamics-365

I need to perform the procedure described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/set-up-dynamics-365-online-to-use-sharepoint-online#configure-a-new-organization), but programmatically.

Some background: I am automating a setup procedure for an existing software product. This product integrates with Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Sales (online, **not** on-prem) and SharePoint Online. The setup process is, as of now, a manual series of steps. One of the steps consists in enabling server-based SharePoint integration for the organization.

I extensively searched Microsoft's documentation on Dynamics 365, specifically the Web API reference docs, but to no avail. I wonder if someone has had an experience doing this and if it is at all possible; if it is not possible we will be forced to have a manual step involved.

So far I have been working with the Dynamics SDK for .NET, but solutions using the Web API or PowerShell are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible.

See [this issue in GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/dynamics-365-customer-engagement/issues/785).

> No it isn't, and is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/integration-dev/get-started-sharepoint-integration#enable-sharepoint-integration
>
> "SharePoint integration for Customer Engagement can only be enabled using the web or Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Outlook. This isn’t supported through SDK."